# Regarding Python IDLE Unicode with kivy

Tags: python, encoding, kivy

I am dealing with application which needs some sort of Korean Language.
I had set the font root but still get the encoding error when I run it with IDLE.

How could I fix it?
**ex39.py code**

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Horse(DragBehavior,Widget):
    horse_state=StringProperty('Not Dragging')
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        tx,ty = touch.pos
        sx,sy = self.pos
        if sx+52>=tx>sx+36 and sy+53>=ty>sy+28:
            self.horse_state = 'Dragging'
        return super(Horse, self).on_touch_move(touch)

class Ex39(Widget):
    pass

class Ex39App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Ex39()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Ex39App().run()
```

**ex39.kv file code**

```
<Horse>:
    size: 100,74
    drag_rectangle: self.x+36, self.y+28, 16, 25
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0
    on_touch_up: self.horse_state = 'Not Dragging'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'horse.png'

<Ex39>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: root.width,root.height
            pos: 0,0
    Label:
        font_name: 'C:\Python34\H2GTRE.TTF'
        pos: 300,root.top-100
        text:
            ('[size=32][color=CC8811]'
            '음표의 길이 익히기'
            '[/color][/size]')
        markup: True
    Horse:
        id: horse_id
        pos: root.width/2.5,root.height/2
    Label:
        pos: 300,100
        text:
            ('[size=32][color=CC8811]'+
            horse_id.horse_state+
            '[/color][/size]')
        markup: True
```

the error message : 
 ***UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 608: illegal multibyte sequence***

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem without kivy? But in any case, you're likely to get more help if you post a [mcve] that focuses on your problem. It looks like you're using Python 3 on Windows, but you should _always_ explicitly mention the Python version (and OS) with Unicode questions, as Unicode handling is significantly different in Python 3 vs Python 2 (and Unicode support in Windows is quite different to how it works in Linux & OSX).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using python 3.4 on windows.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you replace `'음표의 길이 익히기'` with `'\uc74c\ud45c\uc758 \uae38\uc774 \uc775\ud788\uae30'`?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I had changed my strategy to make that senteced embedded in caputred image, then put it as an image. If I meet the similar environment, will try your recommendation.

Comment: That wasn't a recommendation. I don't know kivy, so I can't offer much advice. That string using `\u` escapes is more portable than the original string, but it _probably_ won't solve your actual problem. But if using that string _does_ make a differnce (even if it only cause a different error message to be printed) then that information could be helpful in the problem-solving process.

Comment: I had tried adding u at the front of the string, but it doesn't work(don't know why). Now I had faced another challenging issue. could you help me? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528214/how-to-embed-priority-between-my-image-objects